# Load Current Date into variable

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I load today's date into a variable to use within a `WHERE` clause.  I've tried a number of combinations but unable to get the below to work.

`variable v_today DATE;`

`SELECT SYSDATE INTO v_today FROM DUAL;`

> ERROR: ORA-00905: missing keyword

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL does not support variables, you need to use PL/SQL or check if Oracle SQL Developer supports some kind of text replacement

Comment: Why dont you use `where your_field {comparison operator} sysdate`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - What do you mean? Perhaps bind variables are not mentioned in the SQL Standard, but they are supported by Oracle (the only dialect I am familiar with) and likely by many others. Obviously the OP knows that. The problem is that SQ*Plus does not support the `date` data type for bind variables (even though Oracle SQL does!)

Comment: what do you want to do with this data after ?

Comment: The answer depends on what you are using as your interface. The `variable` command is a SQL\*Plus command (supported by other interfaces as well, for example SQL Developer). SQL\*Plus does not support the `date` data type for bind variables, which means that the first command should have failed already, with a different message. So - what interface are you using, and how did you try to execute these commands (to get the error you got)?

Comment: Hi All - Thanks for your time.  My requirement is to retrieve the previous days data so I will be filtering on: WHERE Date BETWEEN '@CurrentDate-2 AND '@CurrentDate
With '@ representing the variables I need to pass.

Comment: @mathguy - Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Then you don't need variables - something like `between sysdate - 2 and sysdate` would work. You may need to use `trunc(sysdate)` depending on your exact requirement.

Comment: @mathguy: aren't bind variables restricted to PL/SQL?

Comment: Thanks @mathguy - That's worked: 
WHERE Date BETWEEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 2, 'YYYYMMDD') AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD')

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - not exactly sure what that means. If you mean that a statement like `select * from emp where hiredate < :i_hiredate;` is a PL/SQL statement, then you are right; but is that a PL/SQL statement? I think in Oracle world it is considered a SQL statement with a bind variable; it is compiled by and executed by the SQL parser and SQL engine, respectively, not as a PL/SQL program.

Comment: @user3460417 - does that mean that your "date" field is in string data type (perhaps varchar2), and not `date`? That's something that you should fix asap.

Comment: @mathguy: using something like `:i_hiredate` is most certainly not recognized by the server outside of a PL/SQL block.  It might be that the Oracle client tools (e.g. sqlplus) support that, but then the value is replaced before the query is sent to the server. You can most certainly not run that e.g. through plain JDBC or ODBC or through a tool like https://dbfiddle.uk. And it's not documented in the [SQL reference manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/index.html) either as far as I can tell

Comment: @mathguy - That's right.  Something out of my remit unfortunately, the issue has been raised.  How do I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - The SQL parser (with no PL/SQL help) is perfectly capable of parsing a SQL statement (SELECT, UPDATE etc.) with bind variables. The SQL runtime is perfectly capable to read values at memory locations pointed to by the bind variables. HOW those values are written to memory (a feature of the user interface) is irrelevant. A SQL statement absolutely CAN use values passed only at runtime. The Explain Plan for such a statement will show bind variables right in the plan.

Comment: @mathguy: being able to parse the statement does not mean you can actually run it. If that is possible, please show me how passing variables works in plain SQL, e.g. using https://dbfiddle.uk/